# Effect of parens on powershell Get-Content cmdlet

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

What is the effect of putting parens around the Get-Content cmdlet? Why can I read and write to the same file with the parens but not without?

Here is an example of the code in question.

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content SomeFile.sql) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace \"BEFORE\", \"AFTER\" } | Set-Content SomeFile.sql"
```

Is the Get-Content cmdlet holding onto the file handle until the entire command has been executed by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the Get-Content cmdlet holding onto the file handle

Yes.

Without the parens the pipeline will be run each time `Get-Content` outputs one object (ie. one line of text from the file).

On the other hand with the parens the `Get-Content` will be run to completion, creating an array of strings for the whole file, and then the pipeline run for each line.

So in the former case the file will be kept open, while in the second the whole file is read into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Without parens, Get-Content opens the file for read but at the same time you practically try to write to the same file.

Parens force the reading operation to complete before proceeding to the next stage, passing the content through the pipeline.